# How to install libgpuarray and clBLAS in python on mac os x (10.9)?

Tags: python, macos, path, cmake

I'm trying to install libgpuarray (http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) for python on OSX 10.9. I installed CMake 3.0 and are using the UI. I downloaded the libgpuarray and clBLAS source from git and unpacked under Users/user/libgpuarray .. /clBLAS respectively.

Using CMake UI I get the following warning when generating the build:

> MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:
>
> > gpuarray (clBLAS respectively)

Executing 'python setup.py build' results in the following error:

> /Users/i043337/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning:
>
> > ```
> >  "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining  
> >  NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
> > ```
> >
> > '#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
> >      ^
> >     pygpu/gpuarray.c:354:10: fatal error: 'gpuarray/types.h' file not found
> >     '#include "gpuarray/types.h"

Tried to figure out how to set the correct path but I'm lost to be honest.

Any help is more than appreciated!

Latest XCode (incl. DeveloperTools) installed. Python version is 2.7 from python.org and under the following paths (Terminal$ type -a python)

> python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
>   python is /usr/bin/python
>   python is /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running:

```
python setup.py build_ext -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib
```

instead of:

```
python setup.py build
```

and that solved it. You could probably add these to your PATH as an alternative.

Also, for anyone googling this in the future, you may have to modify the link.txt in Build/src/CMakeFiles/gpuarray.dir to:

```
1) omit -arch=i386
2) add -F/Library/Frameworks
```

after running make in the Build/ directory it has you create.

Comment: I have the same error and I ran :'python setup.py build_ext -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib' and still had the same error. I check the link.txt and _F/Library/Frameworks is already there but I have -arch x86_64. Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run

```
make
make install
```

after cmake.

Answer (score -1):

I installed it by following commands:

> mkdir build && cd build
>
> cmake ..
>
> make && make install
>
> cd .. && python setup.py install